# An example of using delegation to replace an object at runtime

Tags: oop, inheritance, runtime, delegation

As stated in the title - can somebody give me an example of using delegation to replace the delegate with another object at runtime? Recently we described the advantages of delegation at the lecture, but no actual example was given to an above benefit.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a C# delegation like this:

```
delegate int Calculate(int x, int y);
```

The benefit here is that, when a method `foo` expects a `Calculate` delegation in its parameter, like this:

```
void foo(Calculate calculate)
{
    var result = calculate(1, 2);
    // ...
}
```

We can easily pass *any method* that matches the signature of the delegation to `foo`. For example, if we already have a method `sum` of class `Math`, we can simply call `foo` like this:

```
foo(mathObject.sum);
```

Without delegation, like in Java, we have to make `Calculate` be an interface, and have to make the `Math` class implements `Calculate`. If we are not allowed to modify source code of `Math` class, we have to write an adapter (Adapter design pattern). That's a lot of extra work.